# Quem é Stack Exchange?

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Tenho utilizado o Stack Overflow por algum tempo e nunca vi uma publicidade sequer por aqui, nem anúncios de uma assinatura paga do site ou algo assim.

Portanto ainda tenho algumas dúvidas sobre o site:

- O que é a Stack Exchange? Uma empresa? Uma organização?
- Se ganham dinheiro com os sites: como?
- Se não ganham: por que oferecem isso de graça? Quem paga os custos?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about

Comment: @Renan Então os sites são mantidos por doações, é isso?

Comment: http://stackexchange.com/about/contact

Comment: Uma resposta em PT em vez de links em EN era porreiro :P

Comment: Existem investidores que aplicaram dinheiro na Stack Exchange. Por alto, o retorno financeiro vem de anúncios e do site Careers, de anúncios de empregos (pagos pelos anunciantes). Os detalhes seria legal ter numa resposta oficial do Gabe.

Comment: que nada.. tudo balela.. eles encontraram uma galinha que bota ovos de ouro... é isso..

Answer (score 25, accepted):

**Não é uma resposta oficial.** Posso estar equivocado.

---

## O que é o Stack Exchange?

Uma empresa. Ela gerencia uma grande rede de sites (171, para ser mais exato) que são similares a esse aqui. Todos com o mesmo sistema de perguntas e respostas, variando no assunto em foco. Via de regra os sites são geridos pela própria comunidade. As regras locais sendo decididas pelos membros, a maior parte da moderação ocorrendo por votação e pelos membros. Essa é a fórmula que tornou o primeiro site, o Stack Overflow (inglês), um sucesso. Criado pelo [Jeff Atwood](http://blog.codinghorror.com/) e [Joel Spolsky](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky).

> Fazer da internet um lugar melhor e trazer respostas de especialistas para as suas perguntas.

## Como eles monetizam?

A maior parte do tráfego da rede é feita por usuários sem conta, vindos diretamente do Google. Para esses usuários é mostrado um banner no corpo da página. Para todos, um banner na barra lateral da direita. Mas isso é apenas para os sites grandes da rede. Todos os pequenos (mais de 100) não possuem propaganda alguma e nenhuma forma direta de *lucro*. Eles são um investimento para o futuro. Esses anúncios também são votados como bons ou ruins por quem os vê. Assim anúncios considerados ruins acabam sumindo e os bons são praticamente conteúdo. A maioria vai realmente ler eles.

Outra forma é o [**Careers**](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/). É um site de empregos para os desenvolvedores. O interessante é que não há cobrança para quem coloca seu currículo lá, ela vem da parte de [quem contrata](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/products).

Não sei dizer de onde vem a maior parte (recentemente a maior parte dos anúncios tem sido da própria SE, então eu diria que a fonte é o Careers). Também desconheço outros meios de monetizar que possam existir.

Comment: No futuro eles vão cobrar muito dos usuários que estão completamente viciados </joke>.

Comment: @bigown Eu vi um relato que o valor da cobrança ia ser inversamente proporcional à quantidade de reputação que você tem, tomando por base a rep do [Jon Skeet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet). Se liga! </joke>

Comment: @bigown se puser uma taxa para edição, voto de fechamento e abertura, o SOpt vai ser o melhor investimento da rede :)

Comment: Se não me engano, já li que tem grandes empresas que pagam um belo $$$ pra instalar um sistema privativo de Q&A.

Comment: Não vi nada de errado na resposta. É basicamente isso mesmo. E se a gente implementasse micro transações para edições, eu estava podre de rico agora.

Comment: Se quiser puxar mais detalhes: [What is Stack Overflow's business model?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79435/185667)

Comment: Ou [What is Stack Overflow's source of income?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255491/1964435). Achei até que era alguém daqui perguntando lá, rs.

Comment: @brasofilo Interessante. Possui alguma fonte/referência?