# O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de "rede social"?

Tags: debate, comportamento

Sei que o SO e o SOPT, assim como todos os sites do SE, são sites de perguntas e respostas, voltados para disseminar o conhecimento, permitindo que nos ajudemos uns aos outros (vide essa [pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1358/quem-e-o-stackexchange)).

Mas, pelo fato de existirem *Favoritos*, *Badges*, *Comentários* e até *Salas de Bate-Papo*, o SOPT pode ser considerado/visto como uma (espécie de) rede social?

Pergunto isso pois tenho uma curiosidade: se o SOPT é uma rede social, há um modo para entrar em contato com alguém diretamente? Ou isso é proibido *by design*, pela própria ideologia do SE?

Ou ainda, posso estar me equivocando completamente (não sou estudioso de redes sociais), e o fato de "(não) existir um meio de comunicação direta" não seja fator determinante para categorizar algo como rede social...

Comment: Vou vou poder responder agora, mas definitivamente não é. O site não é feito para socializar. É um site para colocar pessoas em rede para se ajudar profissionalmente. E o acesso individual é restrito, para não falar impossível por vias normais.

Comment: O único modo de entrar em contato com alguém seria abrir o chat e mencionar a pessoa com @. Assim ela vai receber uma notificação na hora e talvez entre no chat. Fora isso... não. *By design* não somos uma rede social.

Comment: Estou perguntando isso por dois motivos: - curiosidade, mesmo! Uso o SO há anos, e isso sempre me soou como um mistério; - outro dia tive a impressão de que, sem querer, acabei chateando o @bigown por causa de um comentário, e quis pedir desculpas/me explicar, mas não consegui :( Ainda estou me habituando com o formato da escrita dos textos/comentários, e com como as interações ocorrem entre as pessoas dentro do SOPT.

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn não sei que comentário é esse :)

Comment: @bigown Ufa! Que bom! :) Foi esse aqui: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/15721/obtendo-o-caminho-completo-de-um-arquivo-do-cliente-em-asp-net/15733#comment28532_15733

Comment: @carlosrafaelgn foi um comentário normal. Você deu sua opinião e eu dei a minha. Nenhuma problema ali. Você viu problema? Eu não.

Comment: @bigown pois é... olhando agora não tinha nada de mais, mesmo :P Mas, valeu!!! :D

Comment: Tenho uma resposta a meio escrever, falta um pouco de pesquisa... mas o Shog acaba de publicar um resumo excelente do Estado da Nação (SO) que praticamente é uma resposta pra esta pergunta. A frase inicial já é uma pérola, mas adorei o capítulo [***Remando contra maré: o custo de uma rede associal***](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/256084/1287812). c/c @bigown

Comment: Não basta o SO ser voltado para o pessoal da TI, ele é uma rede antissocial *by design* também. E acredite, é melhor que continue assim.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

O conceito original do Stack Overflow era o asterisco no centro deste diagrama de Venn:

[image: Venn diagram]
(fonte: [Stack Exchange Blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/help-us-beta-test/))

E estas características persistem até os dias atuais. Praticamente todo conteúdo do site pode ser editado como uma Wiki (requerendo *peer review* dependendo da reputação do editor), há discussão linear nos comentários como um fórum (notavelmente visto nos tópicos de [debate](/questions/tagged/debate) do Meta), é possível postar uma pergunta juntamente com uma resposta (respeitando o formato Q&A) o que se assemelha a uma publicação de blog, e finalmente nosso sistema de votação e ordenação de perguntas e respostas não é muito diferente do Reddit.

Por design, não temos laços de amizades, nem círculos, nem mensagens pessoais. O objetivo dos sites do Stack Exchange não é socializar, e sim obter respostas e publicar conteúdo de qualidade dentro de um determinado escopo.

Mas é impossível deixar de notar os fenômenos sociais ocorrentes nos sites do Stack Exchange. Praticamente em toda tag popular, eventualmente acaba se formando uma comunidade de *regulars* (pessoas que frequentam e participam em questões da tag regularmente), e obviamente há troca de informações entre estas pessoas e também com novos usuários, geralmente em forma de comentários, respostas e conversações. O mesmo fenômeno também ocorre em salas de chat.

Mesmo que esta troca de informações esteja relacionada a um objetivo profissional, não podemos descartar os valores éticos e sociais que utilizamos nesta comunicação.

Acredito então que sites do Stack Exchange não classificam-se como rede social devido ao seu design e objetivo, mas podem se classificar como uma grande comunidade (com inúmeras sub-comunidades) com o objetivo comum de prover conteúdo de qualidade.

Observação: não tenho formação profissional na área de sociologia nem muita expertise em redes sociais, este post reflete primariamente minhas opiniões e observações.

---

Quanto ao fato de não haver comunicação direta com outro usuário, desde o início dos dois anos que venho participando do Stack Overflow em inglês, sempre que julgo necessário a comunicação com outro usuário -- ex.: enviar um comentário importante sobre uma questão/resposta que acabara de ser deletada (pilhamento de votos negativos que incentivam o usuário a deletar a questão, ou fechamento seguido de exclusão sem nenhum comentário explicativo) -- eu simplesmente abro o perfil deste usuário e posto um comentário em uma de suas perguntas, começando com algo nas linhas de "Quanto a sua pergunta/resposta deletada (link do post caso houver), ...".

Acredito que não haja problemas com esta prática desde que feita por motivos justificáveis, com o intuito de ajudar o usuário (esclarecer o escopo do site, apontar uma fonte que ajude na solução do problema, etc.) e não para simplesmente "dizer um oi" ou vampirar ajuda.

Comment: Sites como o SE e suas variações me parecem ser sim Redes Sociais.
Não saberia categoriar exatamente qual tipo, seja por grau, densidade, centralidade, multiplexidade, vejo o SE como uma rede que atua por cooperação.

Usando o texto que obtive no Livro da "Raquel Recuero", "Redes Sociais na Internet" onde ela cita outro autor:

i) a construção de uma persona através de perfil ou página pessoal
ii) a interação através de comentário
 iii) a exposição pública de rede social de cada ator