# Sugerir videoconferência por algum programa pra ajudar em dúvida

Tags: debate, comportamento

Não sei se existe alguma recomendação pra isso.

Algumas perguntas são muito obscuras mesmo depois de horas tentando entender ou ajudar o AP. [Nessa pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/178405/como-armazenar-m%C3%BAltiplos-checkbox/178415?noredirect=1#comment369062_178415), depois de um tempo editando e acrescentando informações sobre o que o usuário poderia fazer, ele não conseguiu chegar a uma solução. Chamei ele para um chat para ver se conseguia direcionar melhor ele a uma resposta do problema e mesmo assim nada. Vendo que a solução parecia ser mais simples do que era pintada, eu sugeri uma chamada pelo *TeamViewer* (um aplicativo que fornece acesso remoto a máquinas em uma videoconferência, além do compartilhamento de tela) ou então pelo [appear](https://appear.in/), ou ainda pelo *Skype* para tentar ajudar melhor.

Existe algo a respeito disso? Há alguma proibição para videoconferência a fim de tentar ajudar o AP?

E se não, existe alguma política de segurança caso o AP venha a aceitar fazer uma videoconferência?

Comment: Relacionada: [O que fazer quando um usuário solicita contato via e-mail?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/733/91)

Comment: Então, minha intenção nesse caso era ver onde estava o real problema do AP e depois orienta-lo melhor no post.  Como dito no chat, já foram umas 3 perguntas do AP sobre um tema similar, e no chat que chamei ele, ele ainda reportou a ideia de criar mais uma pergunta

Comment: Acredito que a solução ia de acordo com minha resposta, só que ele não entendeu onde e como implementar kk

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio, este usuário acredito que seja um caso bem *sui generis*. Sou usuário já faz algum tempo do SOen e acho que nunca vi um caso assim. Eu respondi uma pergunta dele (também não foi simples para ele compreender) e depois fui ver que ele logo perguntou outra, com o passo seguinte. Por curiosidade, fui ver as perguntas que ele realiza e vi que é uma atrás da outra, como se fosse a cada passo do sistema da peixaria. Não consegui interpretar se é caso de má comportamento (esperar que o SOpt faça o trabalho por ele), ou simplesmente desconhecimento dos rudimentos de programação.

Comment: @mrlew ou ainda desconhecimento de como funciona o SOpt

Comment: Agora comentando brevemente sobre a questão: uma vez eu dei meu email para um usuário do SOen nos comentários e abri um google hangout com ele (guiei ele através do compartilhamento de tela algo relacionado a fazer um deploy no server dele). Mas, apesar de não ter recebido flag, eu nunca vi alguém fazendo isso. Daí sempre fiquei na dúvida se era aceito.

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio pode ser, mas como aconteceu várias vezes (mesmo depois de orientado sobre o funcionamento - por mim, inclusive), me chamou a atenção. Às vezes é difícil detectar quando é caso de abuso (até involuntário) ou só um OP bastante perdido. Eu às vezes me sinto na mesma situação sua. Aliás, faço isto direto, mesmo que o melhor fosse dizer: "cara, vai estudar, pesquisa, tenta, e depois volta aqui se não funcionar" rs. Abraços

Comment: @mrlew normalmente é os dois, a pessoa não sabe, em geral não quer aprender programar, mas pegou um serviço e repassa para o SOpt fazer para ele. Eu nem acho má fé. Esses casos muitas vezes a pessoa é tão sem noção que acha que está fazendo certo. Pra falar a verdade, voltando para a questão, eu acho que isso não resolve o problema, porque a pessoa vai depender desse tipo de ajuda sempre. Ele precisa de um curso (ainda que eu ache que muitas vezes nem isso resolverá). O talento da pessoa pode estar em outro lugar e a gente tá segurando ele :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ninguém pode proibir você de fazer qualquer coisa externa ao site. Até onde eu sei, e posso estar enganado, não é proibido você sugerir o contato. No máximo é desencorajado.

De uma maneira geral [não somos uma rede social](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1361/101). Não há muita facilidade para contato propositalmente. [Já pediram para ter alguma forma de contato extra e os pedidos foram recusados](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57537/140010).

Não posso falar por todos, mas não vejo muito mal se você desejar fazer este tipo de atividade, se a outra parte achar interessante. Aproximação feita com cuidado, sem forçar a barra. O problemas é de vocês, o site não tem nada com isso. A segurança é problema de vocês. Confiar em uma pessoa aleatória na internet é algo que eu não faria, mesmo o risco sendo pequeno. Qualquer coisa fora do site não é problema desta comunidade. Ou seja, não recomendo, mas não tenho nada com isso.

O que eu não gosto mesmo é a pessoa pedir ajuda externa. Primeiro que isso pode ser constrangedor e muita gente pode considerar abusivo. Mas também porque não é o propósito do site. As soluções deveriam ser dadas aqui para todos verem, aproveitarem, escrutinarem.

Então nesse ponto eu não gosto de qualquer coisa feita fora do site. Mas entre eu não gostar e não poder, vai uma grande distância.

O objetivo do site é ajudar o maior número de pessoas e esse tipo de ajuda não se encaixa bem nessa definição, é uma ajuda individual.

Para falar a verdade, eu acho esse tipo de pergunta ruim porque nem é uma pergunta, é realmente um pedido de suporte personalizado. Não me parece que seja o objetivo do site prestar suporte nesse nível. Mas novamente, você é quem sabe o que é bom para você.

Eu acho que se a pergunta começa dar muita volta, ela não é uma pergunta e até deveria ser fechada. Novamente, não posso falar por todos.

Em geral, quando precisa desta ajuda externa, o problema nem está no [escopo do site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Ou pelo menos o problema não é claro ou é amplo demais. Se nós fechamos perguntas porque uma resposta precisa de um tutorial escrito, imagine se precisa de uma intervenção externa.

O que eu vejo como prática comum é apagar qualquer traço de dados de contato em comentários e postagens.

Se alguém me pedir esse tipo de ajuda, eu nem vou dizer que vou cobrar porque também não é objetivo do site ficar caçando clientes desesperados :) Fazer algum negócio pode ser consequência da sua participação.

Outras pessoas podem ter uma visão diferente.

Comment: Então é justamente isso, eu achei a pergunta simples, só que ampla demais pra postar em uma resposta só... Não sei se seria mais prático sugerir ao AP fazer perguntas mais fechadas, me deu a entender que é um iniciante em programação

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio eu acho que seria melhor fazer isso. Eu nunca gosto muito dessa situação. Porque a pessoa não quer aprender a programar, ela quer começar fazendo coisas sem saber o básico, por isso que dá esses problemas. Eu não vejo problema algum a pessoa até mesmo fazer um curso no SOpt, mas passo por passo. Isso ninguém quer fazer. A pessoa assume uma responsabilidade, não dá conta e transfere para outra pessoa que tem que fazer o esforço que ela deveria fazer. Eu não posso proibir ninguém de assumir isso, mas eu não assumo e não recomendo. Mas isso é pessoal. Se alguém discorda, tá blz.

Comment: *Eu acho que se a pergunta começa dar muita volta, ela não é uma pergunta* Olha. É bem isto.

Comment: @bigown exatamente.

Comment: bigown se me permitir, só a sua opinião não me convenceu muito :P como comentado ali em cima pelo @mrlew já rolou com ele, vou esperar mais opiniões a respeito :)

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio minha intenção não foi convencer ninguém :) Se fosse eu seria mais incisivo e mostraria porque isso não é bom pra ninguém. Preferi deixar a resposta meio ambígua mesmo :)

Comment: O principal problema é exatamente compartilhar contatos de forma segura... O apagar não pode ser tão trivial assim, mesmo no chat o que você tem é um *soft* dele por dois minutos... Dito isso, já aconteceu uma vez comigo no SOen, o próprio usuário postou o Skype dele e após resolver o problema, acabei mantendo contato e inclusive ajudando-o em um projeto freelancer ($$$). Meu ponto aqui é, as vezes compensa fazer algo assim, mas você tem que tomar bastante cuidado nesse "salto" do SO para o mundo exterior.

Answer (score 6):

Eu penso que é exacerbado fornecer tanta ajuda.

Tem que saber dosar o que é uma dar uma dica, fornecer uma ajuda rápida e "trabalhar de graça".

Um dos pontos mais importantes que gostaria de citar é que ao fornecer ajuda demais, você se desvaloriza e indiretamente desvaloriza toda a sua classe profissional.

Eu sou a favor do compartilhamento de experiências, pois enriquece a todos e por isso participo aqui. Mas sou contra ajudar em demasia a um caso localizado, pois como citei acima, isso é trabalhar de graça. Na maioria dos casos, é ingenuidade da pessoa que ajuda e/ou de ambos. Até quem pede a ajuda tem boa intenção, mas tem os que vem com intuito de sugar literalmente, pois sabem que sempre tem um ingênuo/bobo para trabalhar de graça.

O site SO não é um centro de suporte técnico gratuito mas eu vejo diariamente diversos usuários agindo como tal, como se estivessem atendendo um cliente. Eu não posso me intrometer pois, como explicado na resposta do @bigown, da qual concordo 100%, ninguém pode ser impedido de fazer isso.

Se quer atender um caso específico pelo chat, videoconferência ou até mesmo pessoalmente, isso é opcional. Cada um faz como quiser. Eu só exorto sobre a questão da desvalorização profissional. Não seja ingênuo demais trabalhando de graça. Saiba dosar os limites.

Eu posto essa resposta pelos pontos particulares citados e também em resposta a comentários onde pedem mais opiniões. Essa é a minha opinião no momento.

Comment: Gostaria que todos pensassem assim. Acaba sendo prejudicial pra todo mundo, até para quem parece estar sendo ajudado, o que obviamente ele só quer a ajuda específica mesmo. Mas vai da consciência de cada um.

Comment: Discordo em parte. Se estou vendo que a pessoa realmente quer aprender e não que façamos o trabalho para ele, não vejo problemas em ajudar, mesmo que muitos achem que está sendo "ajuda demais". Claro, sou totalmente contra esse tipo de ajuda fora do site, pois assim agregará conhecimento apenas para uma pessoa.

Comment: @Randrade o problema é que a pessoa em geral não quer aprender, mesmo que ela diga isto. Ela quer que o conhecimento entre na cabeça sozinho. Ela acha que se alguém fizer por ele, ele vai aprender. Aprender é um processo e é árduo. Se você ver que ela quer aprender, mas precisa de tanto, você vai dar um curso de graça pra ela. Como eu disse, se quer fazer, não sou eu que vou dizer não. Mas não é objetivo do site. Não sei se escrevi ou só pensei. A pessoas pode até fazer um curso aqui, dentro do formato aceito, uma pergunta por vez, um assunto específico em cada, passo por passo.