# stackoverflow sem opção de SEGUIR usuário

Tags: debate, stackexchange

Estou com uma dúvida... 
Na plataforma stackoverflow não consigo SEGUIR usuários... 
Seja em qual perfil esteja..

Afinal porque motivo esta opção não tem ou é escondida?

Alguém?

Comment: E por que você quer seguir um usuário?

Comment: @Costamilam se eu posso seguir as pessoas na rua, eu deveria poder segui-las online tambem

Comment: @Daniel justamente, é uma medida de segurança para eviar problemas. Ja vi caso de gente seguida na rua ter reação agressiva depois de um tempo. :)

Comment: [O SOPT se encaixa na categoria de “rede social”?](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1361/o-sopt-se-encaixa-na-categoria-de-rede-social)

Comment: exatamente por ter diversas pessoas interessantes (programadores) e não ter que ficar pesquisando e coisas do tipo... 
Mas então não é possível ?

Agora entendo porque no profile tem os links das redes socias... 

Obrigado e continuem comentando sua opinião...